# Sitecore Settings Item and Datasource

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have 2 websites each website contains settings item that contains logo and path for navigation folder for each website and navigation folder lives in global folder for each website :

**Website1**

- Settings (Field map to navigation folder for current **website1**)
- Global

  - Navigation Folder

**Website2**

- Settings (Field map to navigation folder for current **website2**)
- Global

  - Navigation Folder

**Question 1** : when i open page editor and update any navigation link title  and click publish from page editor (subitem and related items options are checked) nothing published on the front end website, so i have to go to the current settings item from content editor and publish it. I am sure this happens because there is no relation between current page and the the settings item. is there any way that i can make setting item published on page editor level ?

**Question 2** : I want to make data source path field more dynamic, i  have two websites, both with the same structure tree but different contents, lets say i'm reading navigation folder from datasource not settings item, so if i want to add new item under navigation folder from page editor it should display to me the navigation folder for current website, so the author can easily add navigation item under navigation folder for current website.  how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1.
I think you'll need to select "Edit Related Item" and then publish that. Personally, I prefer things that don't change per-page to be edited from the content editor because it's more of a configuration thing. But that's just personal preference.

Answer 2.
I've used a martketplace module called "[Sublayout Queryable Datasource](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sublayout_Queryable_Datasource.aspx?sc_lang=en)". 
It allows you to uses queries in your datasource locations, which means it can be relative to the current item. In your case it might look something like this:

```
query:ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename = 'Site Root']/Navigation Folder
```

Comment: I will go with change the navigation from content editor only. I agree with you, it is something should don't be change for each page.  and i installed the module it is working 100% with me. Thanks Martin!